# Updating a database row using form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to update an existing row from my database with Django's forms. I have no problem creating a new row but when I try to update an existing one, I get a ValueError ( traceback at the end of the post ).

I understand that my 'product' attribute is mistaken as the primary key but just can't figure why. Here is my code :

**models.py**

```
class Rates(models.Model):
    my_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    taux_comm_1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    taux_comm_2 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    taux_euros = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    taux_uc = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    taux_prud = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rates
        fields = ['product', 'taux_comm_1', 'taux_comm_2', 'taux_euros', 'taux_uc', 'taux_prud']
        labels = {
            'product': "Nom du produit",
            'taux_comm_1': "Taux de commission de production",
            'taux_comm_2': "Taux de commission de portefeuille",
            'taux_euros': "Taux de commission sur l'encours euros",
            'taux_uc': "Taux de commission sur l'encours UC",
            'taux_prud': "Taux de commission sur l'encours UC Prudentes",
    }

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RatesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'readonly':'readonly'})
        self.fields['taux_comm_1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['taux_comm_2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['taux_euros'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['taux_uc'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['taux_prud'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

**views.py**

```
 product = request.session['product']
 if request.method == 'POST':
     rates_form = RatesForm(request.POST)
     if rates_form.is_valid():
         rate = Rates.objects.get(pk=2)  
         rates_form = RatesForm(instance=rate)        
         rates_form.cleaned_data.get('product')
         rates_form.cleaned_data.get('taux_comm_1')
         rates_form.cleaned_data.get('taux_comm_2')
         rates_form.cleaned_data.get('taux_euros')
         rates_form.cleaned_data.get('taux_uc')
         rates_form.cleaned_data.get('taux_prud')
         rates_form.save()
         return redirect('/accountancy/rates/')
     else:
         search_form = SearchProduct()
         rate = Rates.objects.get(pk=2)  
         rates_form = RatesForm(instance=rate, initial={'product': product})
```

***Traceback***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in 
     _get_response
     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in 
     _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
     **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in 
     _wrapped_view
     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<3/vsc-workspace/ola/ola/accountancy/views.py", line 
     109, in view_update_rate
     'update': update,
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, 
     request, 
     using=using)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
     return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
     return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
     return self._render(context)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
     return self.render(context)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/base.py", line 999, in render
     return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/template/base.py", line 978, in 
     render_value_in_context
     value = str(value)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/utils/html.py", line 380, in <lambda>
     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 36, in __str__
     return self.as_widget()
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 118, in as_widget
     **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
     packages/smart_selects/widgets.py", line 125, in render
     available_choices = self._get_available_choices(self.queryset, 
     value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
     packages/smart_selects/widgets.py", line 161, in 
     _get_available_choices
     item = queryset.filter(pk=value).first()
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 836, in filter
     return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in 
     _filter_or_exclude
     clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1253, in add_q
     clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1277, in _add_q
     split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1215, in 
     build_filter
     condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1085, in 
     build_lookup
     lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 18, in __init__
     self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site-                                                      
     packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 68, in 
     get_prep_lookup
     return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/<3/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
     packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 947, in 
     get_prep_value
     return int(value)
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Product A'
```

***Django Traceback***

```
__class__   <class 'django.db.models.fields.AutoField'>
self    <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>
value   'Product A'
```

If you have any idea how I could solve that problem, I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have saved the text value "Product A" in your session, rather than the actual ID of a product. If you can't change what you are saving, you need to get the product instance based on that name.

But you are also doing some very strange things in your view. You shouldn't be re-instantiating the form, and all those `cleaned_data` lines do absolutely nothing at all. Also, be careful with the indentation; the `else` refers to the first `if`, not the second one.

```
product = Product.objects.get(product_name=request.session['product']) # or whatever the name field is
rate = Rates.objects.get(pk=2)  
if request.method == 'POST':
    rates_form = RatesForm(request.POST, instance=rate)
    if rates_form.is_valid():
        rates_form.save()
        return redirect('/accountancy/rates/')
else:
    search_form = SearchProduct()
    rates_form = RatesForm(instance=rate, initial={'product': product})
return render(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem. And also, thank you for the advices you gave me.